# How to select a random position from a 3x3 matrix

Tags: python, matrix, random, element

I have this mathematical problem where I need to select a random element from a matrix. Now I have the code for the matrix and other bits. but I tried to select a random element by using below code but It always selects one complete row, instead of a random single element.

```
def randSelect(self):
    return self.matrix[random.randrange(len(self.matrix))]
```

Here is the complete code as well

```
class Matrix():
    def __init__(self, cols, rows):
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows

        self.matrix = []
        for i in range(rows):
            selec_row = []
            for j in range(cols):
                selec_row.append(0)
            self.matrix.append(selec_row)
    def setitem(self, col, row, v): 
        self.matrix[col-1][row-1] = v

    def randSelect(self):
        return self.matrix[random.randrange(len(self.matrix))] 

    def __repr__(self):
        outStr = ""
        for i in range(self.rows):
            outStr += 'Row %s = %s\n' % (i+1, self.matrix[i])
        return outStr

    a = Matrix(3,3)
    a.setitem(1,2,10)
    a.setitem(1,3,15)
    a.setitem(2,1,10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def randSelect(self):
    row = random.randrange(self.rows)
    col = random.randrange(self.cols)
    return self.matrix[row][col]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I am using a namedtuple as the return so you can get the position of that value as well.

```
import random
from collections import namedtuple

RandomValue = namedtuple("RandomValue", ("Value", "RowIndex", "ValueIndex"))


class Matrix():
    def __init__(self, cols, rows):
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows

        self.matrix = []
        for i in range(rows):
            selec_row = []
            for j in range(cols):
                selec_row.append(0)
            self.matrix.append(selec_row)

    def setitem(self, col, row, v):
        self.matrix[col - 1][row - 1] = v

    def randSelect(self):
        row = self.matrix[random.randrange(len(self.matrix))]
        value = random.choice(row)
        return RandomValue(value, self.matrix.index(row), row.index(value))

    def __repr__(self):
        outStr = ""
        for i in range(self.rows):
            outStr += 'Row %s = %s\n' % (i + 1, self.matrix[i])
        return outStr


a = Matrix(3, 3)
a.setitem(1, 2, 10)
a.setitem(1, 3, 15)
a.setitem(2, 1, 10)
print(random_val.RowIndex)
print(random_val.ValueIndex)
print(random_val.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks electrometro. I am going to try this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `randselect` function needs to access `self.matrix` with two indices. It's an array of arrays, so with only one set of square brackets you get back an array. You'll need a second access to get an individual element.

```
def randSelect(self):
    row = self.matrix[random.randrange(len(self.matrix))]
    return row[random.randrange(len(row))]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a function generate random numbers in the range of your indices and you can use those indices to call a random location in your array

```
    from random import randint
    i = (randint(0,9)) #assuming your range for i is from 0-9
    j = (randint(0,9)) #assuming your range for j is from 0-9
```